# Symfony2 (doctrine2) native sql insert

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, persistence

How to insert data in symfony2 doctrine2 on native sql?

My query

```
insert into propriedades (id,name,descripcion,num_lote,cod_imovel,imovel,convenio,proprietar,cpf,area_ha,perimetro,location,centro) VALUES (nextval('propriedades_id_seq'),'?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?',ST_GeomFromKML('<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>".$terra['coordinates']."</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>'),ST_Centroid(ST_GeomFromKML('<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>".$terra['coordinates']."</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>')))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `$conn->insert('table', $dataArray);`. See [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#insert)

Comment: this dont work with me, because i use psql in queryes and in insert this had in '', transforming the function in a string

Comment: hmm, you can put function strings in a variable then pass it to the `$dataArray`.

Comment: discard previous comment. I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: You can try with [$conn->executeQuery()](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#using-prepared-statements). From the doc it looks flexible enough.

Answer (score 2):

In 2020 you can do something like (example query, adapt it to your params):

```php
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO `user_challenges_claimed`
            SET
                `season_id` = :seasonId,
                `user_id` = :userId,
                `interval_type` = :intervalType,
                `is_claimed` = true
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                `is_claimed` = true
            ;
            ";

        // set query params
        $queryParams = [
          'seasonId'     => $seasonId,
          'userId'       => $userId,
          'intervalType' => $intervalType,
        ];

        // execure query and get result
        $result = $this->manager->getConnection()
          ->executeQuery(
            $query,
            $queryParams
          );

        // clear manager entities
        $this->manager->clear();

        // optional - assert row has been inserted/modified
        if ($result->rowCount() < 1) {
            throw new ChallengeAlreadyClaimedException(
              "[{$seasonId}:{$userId} - {$intervalType}]"
            );
        }
```

`$this->manager` is an object implementing `EntityManagerInterface` (ie `EntityManager`).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not use what you call native sql in a symfony 2 project but the high level Doctrine ORM layer.

However there is a doctrine dbal layer which enables e.g. mysql queries instead of DQL. Here is the reference

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html

Comment: i used the function query() but this dont have statements support, have other function